# Why does Descartes employ the Painter Analogy in the first meditation?

Tags: epistemology

The analogy can be found in Descartes' Meditations. I think the aim is to cast doubt on those things that we take to ground appearance: the simple as opposed to the composite . By denying simples he can deny the sciences that study them .

Comment: *Meditations*, I.

Comment: Yes it is one sorry

Comment: Geometry and Arithmetic, not Logic: logic has no a big place in D's thought.

Comment: By logic I mean something like inference or proof . Any science proceeds in such a manner and they all presuppose assumptions that Descartes is challenging .